# JQuery append elements are going out of parent div width?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a html div which is styled using bootstrap class span9.

```
<div class="span9">
     <div id = "selectedtags" class="well">
     </div>
     <button class="btn" type="button" id="delegatecontent">Create report</button>
</div>
```

What i am trying to achieve is, write a jquery click event on following li tags (20+ li tags in actual ) and append the newly created element inside the #selectedtags div.

```
<li class="dbcol">Location_Id</li>
<li class="dbcol">Location_Name</li>
<li class="dbcol">Location_EN</li>
```

Following is my javascript (Jquery) code to append span tags inside the #selectedtags div.

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
            $('.dbcol').live('click', function () {
                var str = "";
                str = $(this).closest("ul").attr("id");
                var master_name = "";
                if (str == "countryselect") {master_name = "Country_Master"}
                if (str == "stateselect") {master_name = "State_Master"}
                if (str == "locationselect") {master_name = "Location_Master"}
                if (str == "hotelselect") {master_name = "Hotel_Master"}      
                var $newelement = "";

                $newelement += '<span class="label label-info isr" style="margin-top:3px; margin-bottom:2px; margin-right:5px; margin-left:3px; padding:2px;" id = ' +str+ '>';
                $newelement += master_name + '.';
                $newelement += $(this).text() + "  ";
                $newelement += '<i class="icon-remove icon-white"></i>';
                $newelement += '</span>';

                $(this).remove();
                $("#selectedtags").append($newelement);
            });

            $("i").hover(
            function () {
                $(this).removeClass('icon-white');
            });


            $('i').live('click',function() {
                var id = '#'
                id += $(this).closest("span").attr("id");
                var trt = $(this).closest("span").text();
                trt = trt.substring(trt.indexOf('.')+1);
                $(id).append('<li class="dbcol">' + trt +'</li>');
                $(this).closest("span").remove();
            });

            $("#delegatecontent").live('click',function() {
                var strqw ="";
                var final_string = "Select ";
                $('.isr').each( function() {
                    var df = $(this).text();
                    if (strqw == ""){
                        strqw += df;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        strqw += ', '; 
                        strqw += df;
                    }
                });
                final_string += strqw;               
                alert (final_string);
            });
        });
```

Everything works fine, Jquery code do append the newly created span tags in the div however the new tags goes out of the div width (span9) instead of going in the next line.

In addition to the default bootstrap style, following is added:

```
body {padding-top: 40px; padding-bottom: 40px; font-family: 'Monda', sans-serif;}
ul li {cursor: pointer;}
```

Help Please. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

class label label-info is causing the issue here.

```
$newelement += '<span class="label label-info isr" style="margin-top:3px; margin-bottom:2px; margin-right:5px; margin-left:3px; padding:2px;" id = ' +str+ '>';
$newelement += master_name + '.';
$newelement += $(this).text() + "  ";
$newelement += '<i class="icon-remove icon-white"></i>';
$newelement += '</span>';
```

I am using the bootstrap class "label label-info" to style the newly created span tags.

If i remove the class label label-info the code works fine.

```
$newelement += '<span class="isr" style="margin-top:3px; margin-bottom:2px; margin-right:5px; margin-left:3px; padding:2px;" id = ' +str+ '>';
$newelement += master_name + '.';
$newelement += $(this).text() + "  ";
$newelement += '<i class="icon-remove icon-white"></i>';
$newelement += '</span>';
```

I am using a custom style now for span tags.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Try overflow:hidden style on "selectedtags" div.

ie

```
<div class="span9">
     <div id = "selectedtags" class="well" style='overflow:hidden'>
     </div>
     <button class="btn" type="button" id="delegatecontent">Create report</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but i think Overflow:hidden style will make the tags invisible. Instead i want them to display on next line.

Comment: It will hide the content only if the content overflows the entire div. If this solution didn't work, can you please add the image of your div with spans inside

Comment: Yes. Contents will overflow the div width so i want them to go to the next line. I am sorry but this is the first time i am posting a question here so do not have enough reputation to paste images.

Comment: Hi, Thanks your help. It is working as expected now. Bootstrap label class used inside the span class was the problem. I guess bootstrap has defined the CSS property "white space: no wrap" for label class because of which tags were going out of width. As a solution i created a custom style instead of using the default label class of bootstrap.